# Angular 9 cannot extend my class as MatTableDataSource

Tags: angular, datasource

I am trying to create a data source class to populate a mat table from an API call. My goal is to handle pagination and filtering on the client-side because no paginate/filter/sort endpoints exist. Therefore, I want to use a MatTableDataSource. When I try to extend DataSource, it works just fine, but if I change DataSource to MatTableDataSource, I get an error with the Connect method.

Here's my component code:

```
export class CaseDataSource extends MatTableDataSource<any>{

  constructor
    (
      private activeService: ActiveService, private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) 
  
    {
      super();
    }

  connect(): Observable<IActiveCase[]> {

    // Get Moratorium ID
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('activeId');

    return this.activeService.getActiveCases(id)
    .pipe(
      
      catchError((error) => {
        //this.loadingError$ = 
        return of(null);
      }),
      
      switchMap((response) => {
        //let data: IActiveCase[] = [];
        response.data.forEach((item) => this.data.push(item));
        
        return of(this.data);
      })
    );
    }
  disconnect() {}  
  
}
```

Here's the code for the actual API call:

```
  getActiveCases(id): Observable<IActiveCaseApiResponse> {
    const activeCasesUrl = `${this.activeUrl}s/${id}/cases`;
    return this.apiService.getWithLocalErrorHandling<IActiveCaseApiResponse>(activeCasesUrl);

  }
```

The error I'm getting on the Connect method is as follows:

```
Property 'connect' in type 'CaseDataSource' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatTableDataSource<any>'.
  Type '() => Observable<IActiveCase[]>' is not assignable to type '() => BehaviorSubject<any[]>'.
    Type 'Observable<IActiveCase[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'BehaviorSubject<any[]>': _value, value, getValue, next, and 9 more.
```

Here's the html:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
      Active Cases
    </mat-toolbar>
          
    <mat-form-field class="filter">
      <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" (blur)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Ex. ium">
    </mat-form-field>

    <button style="margin: 10px; position: absolute;" mat-raised-button color="primary"  (click)="exporter.exportTable('xlsx', {fileName:'ActiveCases', sheet: 'cases'})" >Export to Excel</button>
  
  <div #PTABLE >
    <mat-table  id="caseTable" mat-table matTableExporter [dataSource]="dataSource" #exporter='matTableExporter'>
      
     <ng-container matColumnDef="Case Id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Case Id</mat-header-cell> 
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let case">{{case.caseID}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Case Number">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Case Number</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let case">{{case.caseNbr}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Effective Date">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Effective Date </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let case">{{case.dateEffective | date}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Expiration Date">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Expiration Date </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let case">{{case.dateExpiration | date}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Case Type">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Case Type </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let case">{{case.caseType }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Primary State">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Primary State </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let case">{{case.primaryState }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="County">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> County </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let case">{{case.county }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="City">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> City </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let case">{{case.city }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Zip">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Zip </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let case">{{case.zipCode }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="headerNames"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: headerNames;"></mat-row>
      
    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

My ultimate goal is to have the data returned by the API call populating a MatTableDataSource and handling all pagination/sorting/filtering completely on the client-side. I have a good grasp of what needs to be done with all of that, but I need to get this data into a MatTableDataSource.

Comment: Can you provide the html associated with the component, so we can see the Material Table?

Comment: You need to specify type when you extend MatTableDataSource, check if this works.

export class CaseDataSource extends MatTableDataSource< **IActiveCase** >{

Comment: I added the html, and changed the type to `export class CaseDataSource extends MatTableDataSource<IActiveCase>` but I'm still getting the same error on the Connect method.